# Does anybody know of a framework that can host a local set of html/css/javascript files as an App?

Tags: android, html

If I a webapp i.e. set of html(canvas)/css/javascript files, Is there something I can use to turn that into an android app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/)?

Comment: Nice! That one looks like what I need